# Logstash ignore document update if document time field in log is older than current time field in document

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash to process a log file.  One of the fields in my log file is of type Date and has this format: yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS

I read each line of my log file into a document in an index in Elasticsearch. A sample line from my log file looks like this:

```
{"location":"Earth","sku":"0000000","quantity":"5","time":"20180813124704961"}
```

Which in turn my document structure in my index looks like so:

```
{
    "_source": {
      "sku": "0000000",
      "time": "20180813124704961",
      "location": "Chicago",
      "quantity": 5
    }
  }
```

My logs are constantly updating and I want to prevent my index from having stale data.  How can I check against the time field in my index to see if it is older or newer than the same line the next time the log file gets processed?

For example, if the time field in the same line of the log file were to change to be older the time above, then the document should not be updated, BUT, if the time field value was newer, then it should be updated.

Here is what I have tried (logstash.conf):

```
elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
    index => "logstash"
    scripted_upsert => true
    script => "if(ctx.op == create || params.event.get('time').compareTo(ctx._source.time) > 0) ctx._source = params.event"
  }
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting an answer for those who may also stumble across a similar problem.

```
scripted_upsert => true
    action => "update"
    script_lang => "painless"
    script_type => "inline"
    script => "if(ctx.op == 'create' || params.event.time.compareTo(ctx._source.time) > 0) ctx._source = params.event;"
```

The documentation is not super clear on this, but you can access fields from the document directly by stepping into the json via `params.event.YOUR_FIELD.compareTo`...and then you can do whatever script you like with your data.

`Event` is the default variable name but you get to event via `params`